# RichFaces rich:clientId within facelets

Tags: richfaces, facelets

I'm trying to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"/>
<ui:composition ....>
    <h:inputText id="#{id}InputText" value="#{value}"/>

    <rich:calendar id="#{id}Shevron"
        popup="true"
        datePattern="ddMMyy"
        showInput="false" 
        todayControlMode="hidden"
        enableManualInput="false"
        showApplyButton="false"
        updateDays="14"
        ondateselected="alert('#{rich:clientId('#{id}Shevron')}');"
        inputClass="xwingml-input"/>
</ui:composition>
```

The problem I'm facing here is that the actual client id is generated for my facelts 
components. Is there a way to pass an id to rich:clientId like this? If not how would one go about this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `rich:clientId` does it to render `document.getElementById()` and provide the full id.

So don't use `#{rich:clientId('#{id}Shevron')}` and just use `document.getElementById('#{id}Shevron');` and ensure that you specify the full ID (ie. including the form ID etc)

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but here I write down my solution in case it helps someone.

You can pass parameters to JSTL functions without needing the evaluation operators ( #{} ${} ). Take a look at this [String length example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html).

So if your "id" wasn't dynamically generated this will solve your problem:

```
#{rich:clientId(id)}
```

But in your case you need to define an additional variable to store your dynamic id:

```
<c:set var="myDynamicID" value="${id}Shevron"/>
```

And then use it to obtain the client UI.

```
#{rich:clientId(myDynamicID)}
```