# JSF richfaces getElementById

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using jsf2 and richfaces 4.X how can i get the richfaces enabled input field's current value ? equal to getElementById('field_name').vlue

I tried some of the methods named like findcomponent.value and element.value but they give me old value which was while page was loaded b/c findcomponent and element method returns server side UI.components instead client side components ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are to use `rich:clientId` function to render a correct identifier into your java script.

For example:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("#{rich:clientId('field_name')}");
```

See also [RichFaces rich:clientId within facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956983/richfaces-richclientid-within-facelets)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the HTML generated, you could see that every JSF / RF element has his id like :. For example:

```
<h:form id="frmSample">
    <h:inputText id="txtSample" value="#{mybean.someTextValue}" />
</h:form>
```

The HTML generated will be:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="frmSample:txtSample" />
</form>
```

So, in JavaScript you could reference the element by this id.

```
var txtValue = document.getElementById('frmSample:txtSample').value;
```

Also, for the RF composite HTML components like `rich:tab` or `rich:calendar` you could use the component ID generated by HTML but I'll recommend `"#{rich:clientId('field_name')}"` as @DRCB has explained in his post.

Answer (score 0):

To get the richfaces components values use the rich:component and the getValue() methods. 
To get the jsf library components values use the rich:element and the value JS methods.


Example:

```
<h:form>
     <h:inputText id="textField" value="#{bean.value1}" />
     <a4j:commandButton value="displayTextField" action="doSomething()"
       onclick="alert('v:'+ #{rich:element('textField')}.value); return true;" />

     <rich:inplaceInput id="richField" value="#{bean.value1}" />
     <a4j:commandButton value="displayRichField" action="doSomething()"
       onclick="alert('v:'+ #{rich:component('richField')}.getValue()); return true;" />
</h:form>
```

They both work even in a rich:dataTable, without adding the id of the datatable or something. Richfaces is quite smart and find the ids of the 'current row'
example:

```
<h:form>
     <rich:dataTable id="mydatatable" value="bean.findValues()" var="myvar">

         <rich:column>

              <h:inputText id="textField" value="#{myvar.text1}" />
              <a4j:commandButton value="displayTextField" action="doSomething()"
                   onclick="alert('v:'+ #{rich:element('textField')}.value); return true;" />
         </rich:column>

         <rich:column>

             <rich:inplaceInput id="richField" value="#{myvar.text2}" />
             <a4j:commandButton value="displayRichField" action="doSomething()"
                  onclick="alert('v:'+ #{rich:component('richField')}.getValue()); return true;" />
         </rich:column>

     </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```